# why does python automatically flip image vertically

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I experiment some strange behavior. I have a folder with about 400 JPG images. For some reason, when I load certain images with PIL or matplotlib, the image is flipped vertically. This only happens for some images and I have no idea why. Has anyone experimented something similar or has any idea, what might be happening here?

I am posting an Image as an example, but I am not sure if the problem is reproducable:

```
img = plt.imread('IMG_4613.JPG')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show();
```

[image]

Original Image:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the camera will record it's orientation and the software will automatically rotate the image to compensate.

Comment: btw, your image in the example is rotated, not flipped

Comment: Your camera might be recording its orientation in the EXIF data https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html?highlight=Exif%20orientation%20#PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose Try using `exiftool` to check your input images.